# How to make create and retrieve work in the same serializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i have a somewhat tangled problem, I have the following models

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and the serializers

```py
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = '__all__'

class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    terminal = ModelASerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = '__all__'
```

when I want to create a `ModelB` object including the model_a_id it has 2 responses depending on whether I put the `read_only=True` or `False`

I would like that when I try to create via `POST` in an object of `ModelB` I only have to send the `mode_a_id`, but at the same time when I do a `GET` it returns the serialized data of `ModelASerializer` in the `model_a` field.
If I put the `read_only = True` it only works to receive the serialized data in `GET`, but via `POST` I cannot assign an id to `model_a`

in case of `read_only=False`, I can't assign the id to that object either since it asks me for a dictionary, I imagine to create a new `ModelA` Object, but I only want to assign one that already exists.

A solution may be to place the serializer with another variable name, but I would really like it to be the same for both `POST` and `GET`.

EDIT #1: examples of the json expected

make a GET for a simple view of ModelB object

```json
{
    "model_a" : {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "foo"
    }
}
```

and a POST like:

```json
{
    "model_a" :  1
}
```

that retrive of POST the same json as a GET:

```json
{
    "model_a" : {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "foo"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide, what sort of response you are expecting in both GET and POST method.

Comment: @PiyushKumar Added JSON examples.

Answer (score 1):

Just override `to_representation()` method of your ModelBSerializer like the following.

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = '__all__'

class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    terminal = ModelASerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        pre_represented_data = super().to_representation(instance)
        pre_represented_data['model_a'] = ModelASerializer(instance.model_a).data
        return pre_represented_data
```

And if you seriously don't want the `id` of ModelB in the GET call then just delete the key from pre_represented_data like following.

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = '__all__'

class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    terminal = ModelASerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        pre_represented_data = super().to_representation(instance)
        pre_represented_data['model_a'] = ModelASerializer(instance.model_a).data
        del pre_represented_data['id']  # deleting id of ModelB
        return pre_represented_data
```